# How to use dateFromString in mongoDB in arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

After hours of searching and reading docs and experimenting, I am no closer to understanding my super specific question.

My mongo documents look like this :

```
{
container:{
    objects: {
         [id1]: [{meta:{time:string}}, {meta:{time:string}}],
         [id2]: [{meta:{time:string}}, {meta:{time:string}}],
         ...
         [idx]: [{meta:{time:string}}, {meta:{time:string}}],
        }

  }
}
```

And I need to update it so that all of my times are Dates and not Strings.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide real documents for this situation, when you say time as string, there are a various formats people usually store time into strings(05/01/2020 or 05-01-2020 or isoString or 01-05-2020 alot), unless we know which format your data is - no one can help you with a query to convert existing string into date(just forget about arrays or update part, first conversion from string to date is also imp)..

Comment: the one with a z in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate `object1` and `object2` and apply `$dateFromString`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "container.objects.object1": {
        $map: {
          input: "$container.objects.object1",
          as: "obj",
          in: {
            meta: {
              time: {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$$obj.meta.time",
                  format: "%Y-%m-%d"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "container.objects.object2": {
        $map: {
          input: "$container.objects.object2",
          as: "obj",
          in: {
            meta: {
              time: {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$$obj.meta.time",
                  format: "%Y-%m-%d"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fxQ9wh7_c8m)

**NOTE:** To update your data, iterate with `.forEach` and save them back

```
db.collection.aggregate(...).forEach(function(doc){
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

Comment: I am grateful for your response, but its not just 2 objects, its an object of key value pairs

Comment: @darthzeran We give you solution based on your samples. Post more representative samples and I could analyze it

Comment: @darthzeran Post please valid JSON

Comment: the [idx] is supposed to represent an random uuid, so I cannot post my full json, because i cant give them out